# Download de PDF do servidor FTP, e salvar direto na máquina do cliente - PHP

Tags: php, pdf, ftp, download

Estou há uns dias tentando solucionar esse problema!

Preciso baixar uns pdf's que estão no servidor FTP direto no navegador do cliente, porém quando eu faço isso forçando os headers, o arquivo até baixa porém corrompido "Falha ao carregar documento PDF."

Segue o código abaixo:

```
$ftp_arquivo = "path/arquivo.pdf";
$ftp_host = "ftp.exemplo.com.br";
$ftp_port = "21";
$ftp_username = "usuario";
$ftp_senha = "senha";


ob_start();

$fcon = ftp_connect($ftp_host);
$conecta = ftp_login($fcon, $ftp_username, $ftp_senha);
ftp_pasv($fcon, true);

$arquivo = basename($ftp_arquivo);

ftp_get($fcon, $arquivo, $arquivo, FTP_BINARY); 

ftp_close($fcon);


$file = $arquivo;

$size = filesize($arquivo);

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type:application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Length: {$size}");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file . "\"");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');

ob_clean();
flush();
```

Comment: Júlia, será que a pasta no destino existe? Outra coisa, não seria melhor dar um ```ftp_chdir($fcon, $path);``` para entrar na pasta onde o arquivo está?

Comment: Rodrigo, acrescentei o ftp_chdir($fcon, $path); e até coloquei um echo pra ver se estava no diretório correto, e está sim! Existe a possibilidade do erro estar na hora que faço o ftp_get e depois passo pro header?!

Comment: Testei várias coisas aqui Julia, porém sem sucesso também... Alterei o ```Content-type``` para ```application/pdf``` Ao iniciar o download ele reconhece meu arquivo pdf de exemplo com o tamanho de 1MB, porém ele baixa outra coisa de 1Kb... Gostaria de ver mais pessoas te ajudando porque isso me interessa saber também!

Comment: Não deveria ter um `echo file_get_contents($arquivo);` para fazer o download?